# Can I make one method of class run in background?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to make a simple server-like program, which can run in loop and read and process messages sent to it. And when  I start it like `Server().start` it obviously runs in loop forever. Is there a way to run it in background and feed it with data, which will be proceeded?

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.messages = []
        self.running = False     

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self.work()

    def  send_mess(self, message):
        self.messages.append(message)

    def handle_mess(self):
        for mess in self.messages:
            self.do_calculations(mess)        

    def work(self):
        while self.running:
            self.handle_mess(self)
            self.do_some_important_stuff()

    def do_some_important_stuff():
        pass
    def do_calculations():
        pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you could use [`Thread` class from the `threading` module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html?highlight=threading%20module#thread-objects).

It works by inheriting it and redefine `run` method. Then you issue `obj.start()` and you'll make `start` method run in parallel.

Roughly, your class can be define like this (I made some corrections to some methods in order to run)

```
import threading

class Server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Server, self).__init__()
        self.messages = []
        self.running = False     

    def run(self):    # changed name start for run
        self.running = True
        self.work()

    def send_mess(self, message):
        self.messages.append(message)

    def handle_mess(self):
        for mess in self.messages:
            self.do_calculations(mess)        

    def work(self):
        while self.running:
            self.handle_mess()
            self.do_some_important_stuff()

    def do_some_important_stuff(self):
        pass
    def do_calculations(self):
        pass


s = Server()
s.start()    # now is in another another thread running
s.join()     # wait for it to finnish
```

**IMPORTANT:** Copying @Alfe comment which I found extremely useful:

> One MUST point out that by entering the world of concurrency (by threading) one opens a nasty can of worms. OP, you really really should read a little more about concurrency problems which occur in parallel environments. Otherwise you are bound to end with a serious problem sooner or later which you have no clue how to solve. See that you understand `Queue.Queue` (`Queue.queue` in Python3) and the things in threading like `Event`s, `Lock`s, `Semaphore`s and what they are good for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: One _MUST_ point out that by entering the world of concurrency (by threading) one opens a nasty can of worms.  OP, you really really should read a little more about concurrency problems which occur in parallel environments.  Otherwise you are bound to end with a serious problem sooner or later which you have no clue how to solve.  See that you understand `Queue.Queue` (`Queue.queue` in Python3) and the things in `threading` like `Event`s, `Lock`s, `Semaphore`s and what they are good for.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be:

```
def start(self):
    self.running = True
    thread = Thread(target = self.work, args = ())
    thread.start()
```

To start just one background thread (another way is to extend the threading.Thread class).
Or:

```
def work(self):
    while self.running:
       message = self.handle_mess(self) # gets a message
       def threaded_part(m):
           self.do_some_important_stuff(m)
           self.do_other_important_stuff(m)
       thread = Thread(target = threaded_part, args = (message))
       thread.start()
```

To start a thread for each message you receive. Anyway, with a thread pool it would probably be better.